# Setting Up server using express

Tags: express, installation

I got the error while trying to install express in the node_modules. Any insight to while this is happening.

````
$ npm install express
npm ERR! file C:\Users\callo\OneDrive\Desktop\PROFESSIONAL\Devops_FullStack Internship\Online_learning\week 3\es6modules\es6modules\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token / in JSON at position 157 while parsing near '...emon server.js"
npm ERR! JSON.parse     //"test": "echo \"Er...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\callo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-01T06_31_01_997Z-debug.log ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I later found out that the problem was in package.json. I removed extra / in package.json and that resolved it for me.